# unable to access local iis from remote desktop

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

Here is the error I get:

> ```
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
> ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server 
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.26.17.212:8080\r\n  
>  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.ServicePoint.
> ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)\r\n 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.
> EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Threading.
> Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at Web_Api_ServerTest.Controllers.EmployeeController.
> <Login>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
>  ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
>  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.26.17.212:8080\r\n  
>  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.
> Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)\r\n
> ```

Here is the code I think is causing this:

```
 [ActionName("Login")]
    [HttpGet]
    [CacheFilter(TimeDuration = 100)]
    public async Task<string> Login([FromUri]string id, string netPwd)
    {
      using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClientHandler hndlr = new HttpClientHandler();
                hndlr.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(hndlr);

                 client.BaseAddress = new 
               Uri("http://172.26.17.212/webapi_publish/api/employee/Login/" 
                 + id + "?netpwd=" + netPwd);

                // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
               new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    dt = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                dt = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        return dt;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error you get, it looks like your not able to access the http port of the server.

Ask your administrator to check your network settings are ok, or allow this port's access in your firewall.